HubSpot API Contact ignore property field hs_marketable_status
I'm having issues with the hs_marketable_status and hs_marketable_reason_type properties when creating a contact in HubSpot via the API.
Problem
When trying to create a new contact using the following endpoint:
https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/batch/create
with this payload:
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "email": "example@hubspot.com",
                "firstname": "Jane",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "phone": "(555) 555-5555",
                "hs_marketable_status": "true",
                "hs_marketable_reason_type": "INTEGRATOR_SET"
            }
        }
    ]
}

The API ignores the hs_marketable_status and hs_marketable_reason_type fields entirely. I have tried providing these values as strings, booleans, or even irrelevant strings like "Hello", and nothing seems to work. The values are not validated and appear to be simply ignored.
I used different methods to send requests:

cURL
Postman
HubSpot Python SDK(github.com/HubSpot/hubspot-api-python)
I verified the API key and permissions are correct.
I tried both giving true as a string or as a boolean.
I tried both batch and basic API. The example from postman is using batch API.

Additional Context:
I understand that hs_marketable_status is a read-only field that cannot be edited after creation. However, my goal is to create contacts as marketable from the beginning.
Questions:

Is hs_marketable_status dependent on another property or
configuration?
Is there any official documentation that outlines how to set this
property during contact creation?
Is there a workaround to set contacts as marketable from the start?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!
